# How to make data column clickable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make a datacolumn clickable, such that when the user clicks on it, an overlay opens up. I've tried to add a IconButton, but i doesn't work. Does anyone has an idea how to do that properly in flutter?

Code:

```
 SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: DataTable2(
                minWidth: 600,
                columnSpacing: defaultPadding,
                columns: const [
                  DataColumn(
                    IconButton( <------------- This doesn't work
                      icon: Icons.abs,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    label: Text("Car ID"),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Date")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Avg. Speed")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Video File")),
                ],
                rows: List.generate(demoRecentFiles.length,
                    (index) => recentFileDataRow(demoRecentFiles[index])),
              )),
```

Answer (score 0):

To make data column clickable, just wrap your label with GestureDetector() widget.

```
DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(onTap: (){
              print('Hey');
            }, child: Text(
              'Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            )),
          )
          ,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`label` attribute of `DataColumn` as well as positional parameter of `DataCell` in `DataRow` can be any widget. So feel free to use any clickable widget there. Here's working snippet with `IconButton` like you wanted it to be. You can try it in Dartpad.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text('It works'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('Ok'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('1')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('2')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```